# AWS export task failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on exporting individual log streams of the last year from Cloudwatch log groups to the S3 bucket using AWS CLI. However, facing the below errors. Can anyone help me with this?

`aws logs create-export-task --task-name "name of the task" --log-group-name "log group" --log-stream-name-prefix "stream" --from "1615374910975" --to "1640995200000" --destination "bucket name" --destination-prefix "path"`

Note: I have already exported some logs to the same s3 bucket.
Retention period: 1 year

Errors:

`This task has failed likely due to export being too large, please shorten the request window.`

`Export task failed unexpectedly. Please try again later.`

Comment: The message tells you what to do, what problem are you having?

Comment: When exporting logs from Cloudwatch to S3 the following error interrupts the process. `This task has failed likely due to export being too large, please shorten the request window.`

Comment: Have you shortened the export window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this error due to exporting large data and large time periods (yearly). Then, I shortened the time period from yearly to monthly. That is works for me.